# Autosave interval remains default despite wp-config.php defines

Tags: wp-config, constants, autosave

On site which I maintain there are writers that spend a lot of time editing single posts, and autosave every minute is very painful for them. So they asked me to set it to at least 10 minutes.

I found an official way to change autosave interval, so I've put this line in wp-config (at the end of it and there is no duplicate of this constant in this file):

```
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 600);
```

But it didn't help. I checked everything, browser cache, memcache, redis cache and even waited a few days.

But Wordpress still uses default 60 seconds to run autosave script. Any ideas why is this happening or how to overcome this?

Comment: You've verified it's the autosave not the heartbeat ping? The latter doesn't necessarily mean an autosave and is used for other things

Comment: Yes, it saves a draft every minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put any defines in the end of the `wp_config.php` it is actually explicitly stated in it ;) Every define you add should be above the line saying

> /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Anything after that will have impact only **after** wordpress had finished to process the request

Comment: Thanks it helped. The problem was that previous developer changed wp-config.php a lot so it was too hard to see this comment.